# Is it possible to use _analyze ElasticSearch endpoint on index, not on the plain text?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, analysis

I am performing NLP analysis in ElasticSearch. I found [`_analyze` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

The issue is that in the request, I need the `text` keyword. I want to analyze the field in the index to get the most frequent words (aka keywords).

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I perform NLP analysis on the index specifying a specific field, not a plain text?